# Cliping a Raster to a polygon producing errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, landsat, extract

I'm clipping a raster to a polygon using extract by mask (Arc 10.5). This produces a very skewed result. White washed image. I've tried using raster clip, but the "use input features for clipping geometry" option is grayed out so that I can't check it meaning I'm not getting the result I want. Some details: when I enable DRA the image looks much better. But I need to be able to view it properly without clicking enable DRA.

Any insight as to why the clipping geometry option is grayed out would be great. I thought it might be a memory issue but I have deleted a lot of data and still no change. Prior to the clip the image is a landsat 8 16 bit image with compression type LZ77. After the extract by mask the image becomes compression type LZW. The image that worked properly was compression type none, but when I export the data and select compression type none the image somehow becomes 32 bit.

Comment: Sounds like it could be something with the environment settings (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/what-is-a-geoprocessing-environment.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with this when the two were in different projections. Make sure that both the raster and the polygon are in identical datum/projections.